# How to access Request.Properties outside of Web API Controller

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm setting a Property on `Request.Properties` inside a `DelegatingHandler` after I pluck some data out of a header on an incoming request to a Web API.

This all works fine. I can also access `Request.Properties` from within the controller as well as in my Action and Exception filters. However, I also need to access this data from outside of the controller (I call a business layer class from the controller). It is data I want to include in some logs in other places,

I can see `HttpContext.Current` from this class, and I can see the original header from here, so I guess I could pluck it out again, but since I have already done this and put it in the Properties it seems to make more sense to get it from there. However, I don't seem to have access to the Request.Properties from anywhere else.

If this isn't the right way to do this, how else would I pass around this per-request data so that it was accessible from anywhere on the stack in Web API?

Comment: Use something like [AutoFac](http://autofac.org/) for DI (dependency injection). I have a good example I actually just answered the other day [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35826744/1260204) (*sorry for the shameless plug of my answer*). If you go the listed `Solution 2 - IoC / DI` you can reuse this. Update the `WebUserInfo` class (at the top of the answer) and interface as you see fit. Add the Autofac framework. And now inject your `IUserInfo` interface in the constructors of your service layer, Autofac will take care of the rest and now you have access where ever you need it.

Comment: Note if you pluck from `HttpContext.Current`, the code will only work when running under IIS. Using OWIN to self-host a web api, there is no `HttpContext.Current` (unless your application sets it up manually).

Comment: Forgot to mention: you will need to register your service types with DI framework as well and they can be injected into your web api controllers. If you are using multiple projects make sure that common interfaces are defined in a central location. But situations like this is where a DI framework really shines.

Comment: @Igor thanks for the suggestion. I am an advocate of DI but I think it is a little heavy to use in this situation. As well, my client isn't familiar with it at all, so I wouldn't want to unleash the concept on them for such a minor need. The day is coming, but not right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also need to access [`Request.Properties`] data from outside of the controller (I call a business layer class from the controller). It is data I want to include in some logs in other places... However, I don't seem to have access to the `Request.Properties` from anywhere else. If this isn't the right way to do this, how else would I pass around this per-request data so that it was accessible from anywhere on the stack in Web API?

You can get it from `HttpContext.Current`, though it is less than ideal. Keep in mind that if any other non-web applications consume the same business layer, then `HttpContext.Current` would be null. `HttpContext.Current` is only non-null when you are running in IIS, and an IIS thread is handling the execution of the request stack. If you ever plan to self-host the web api using OWIN without IIS, there will be no `HttpContext.Current`.

Personally, if the data really is important enough to be passed into the business layer to be logged, then I would just pass it to the business layer method:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SomeAction(SomeModel model) {
    ... other code
    someBusinessLayerObject.SomeMethod(arg1, arg2, Request.Properties["myHeaderKey"]);
}
```

...If you need other values from `Request.Properties`, then you can just pass the whole dictionary to the methods that will end up using its values.

A third option if you are using an inversion of control container would be to add some kind of scoped object dependency class and put the data in there. Then constructor inject it into your business layer class:

```
public interface IHaveRequestData {
    IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class RequestData : IHaveRequestData {
    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
}

// ioc registration pseudocode
iocContainer.Register<IHaveRequestData, RequestData>(Lifetime
    .WhateverYouNeedSoThatOneOfTheseGetsCreatedForEachWebRequest);

public class SomeController : ApiController {
    private readonly IHaveRequestData RequestData;
    public SomeController(IHaveRequestData requestData) {
        RequestData = requestData;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SomeAction() {
        // you may even be able to do this part in an action filter
        RequestData.Properties = Request.Properties;
    }
}

public class SomeBusinessLayerComponent {
    private readonly IHaveRequestData RequestData;
    private readonly ILog Log;
    public SomeBusinessLayerComponent(IHaveRequestData requestData, ILog log) {
        RequestData = requestData;
        Log = log;
    }

    public Task SomeMethod() {
        Log.Info(RequestData["myHeader"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This was the approach I was thinking of taking (grab it in controller, pass it to business layer) but I was hoping there was some other way to get it in there. Luckily it is only one layer down from the controller. If it was needed in a bunch of places I would probably consider DI.